# Equation Solving with NSolve

Tags: equation-solving

I have the code:

```
G = 0.1;
β = 0.5;
ωc = 10;

integralgamma[ω_, τ_] := 
 4 G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] ((1 - 
   Cos[ω τ])/ω^(2)) Coth[β ω/2];

mem : γ[τ_] := 
mem = NIntegrate[
 integralgamma[ω, τ], {ω, 0, Infinity}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 15, PrecisionGoal -> 2, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]

  Table[NSolve[{Sin[χ]*Cos[α] == 
   1/Sqrt[3] *Exp[-γ[τ]] && 
    Sin[χ]*Sin[α] == 1/Sqrt[3]*Exp[-γ[τ]] && 
     Cos[χ] == 1/Sqrt[3], 
      0 <= χ <= π && 
       0 <= α <= 2 π}, {χ, α}], {τ, 0, 2, 
        0.1}]
```

But I get the errors:

> NSolve::ratnz: NSolve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.
>
> {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, \
>   {}, {}, {}, {}}

When I remove the time dependent exponential factor, I am able to solve the equation. What's going on?

---

**Edit:**

Another try:

I first table the expression for the time-dependent exponential factor:

```
FunctionList[χ_, α_] = 
 Table[Sin[χ]*Cos[α] == 
  1/Sqrt[3] *Exp[-γ[τ]] && 
   Sin[χ]*Sin[α] == 1/Sqrt[3]*Exp[-γ[τ]] && 
    Cos[χ] == 1/Sqrt[3], {τ, 0, 2, 0.1}];
```

It works; I get a list with 21 elements.

When  run:

```
NSolve[{#, 
 0 <= χ <= π && 
  0 <= α <= 2 π}, {χ, α}] & /@ 
   FunctionList[χ, α],
```

I get the same errors. Suggestions?

Comment: You are giving `NSolve` a system of 3 equations in 2 variables (treating `tau` as a parameter). Are you sure that these equations even have a solution? If your system is over determined, it makes sense that `NSolve` cannot find solutions.

Comment: Possibly the problem is that the equations are overdetermined. They are consistent, up to numeric fuzz, but it is possible that the methods being used do not manage to catch that in the presence of approximate machine floats.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit This command, for instance, works: `NSolve[{Sin[\[Chi]]*Cos[\[Alpha]] == 1/Sqrt[3] && 
   Sin[\[Chi]]*Sin[\[Alpha]] == 1/Sqrt[3] && Cos[\[Chi]] == 1/Sqrt[3],
   0 <= \[Chi] <= Pi && 0 <= \[Alpha] <= 2 Pi}, {\[Chi], \[Alpha]}]`

Comment: Try any values on the right hand sides of the three equations in so far as the sum of their squares is one. This is just me trying to solve for the polar and azimuthual angles for points specified on a unit sphere in spherical coordinates.

Comment: If the aforementioned command works, shouldn't it work for the case I'm trying to solve: tacking on time dependent exponential factors, which effectively means I am trying to solve more than one equation.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau

Comment: Also I think some of these really are not consistent. Here is an example that I explicitly reformulated as a polynomial system in the trigs. `In[135]:= NSolve[{ca*sx == 0.030141370921275404`, 
  sa*sx == 0.030141370921275404`, ca^2 + sa^2 == 1, cx^2 + sx^2 == 1, 
  ca == 1/Sqrt[2]}, {ca, sa, cx, sx}]

Out[135]= {{ca -> 0.707106781187, sa -> 0.707106781187, 
  cx -> -0.999091084695, 
  sx -> 0.0426263355454}, {ca -> 0.707106781187, sa -> 0.707106781187,
   cx -> 0.999091084695, sx -> 0.0426263355454}}` Notice that I change from Cos[x]==1/Sqrt[3] to Cos[a]==1/Sqrt[2]. That was necessary.

Comment: "Try any values on the right hand sides of the three equations in so far as the sum of their squares is one. " Maybe I'm just confused, but the sum of squares on the right hand sides of your equations (the ones with the exponents) doesn't seem like it equals 1 for `gamma != 0`. The system of equations without the exponents is working because it has a solution; I don't think there exists a solution for the system WITH the exponents.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Yeah, you're right. I was referring to the system when I set `\[Tau]` = 0. But shouldn't I have a solution in that case as well? All this is representations of 3 points in spherical coordinates. The effect of the exponential factor is to make the radius less than one, but shouldn't I be able to solve for the polar and azimuthal angles given values of the three rectangular coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the spherical coordinates given the rectangular coordinates, can't you just use:

```
Table[
    ToSphericalCoordinates[{1/Sqrt[3]*Exp[-γ[τ]],1/Sqrt[3]*Exp[-γ[τ]],1./Sqrt[3]}],
    {τ,0,2,0.1}
]
```

?